# How to return next-auth authOptions from an async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have to get values from `AWS Secrets Manager` and load them into the `next-auth` authOptions config. I have the implementation like this:

```js
export const buildAuthOptions = async () => {
  const secrets: AuthSecrets = await getSecret(
    'secret_name',
  );

  return {
    providers: [
      CognitoProvider({
        clientId: secrets.cognitoClientId,
        clientSecret: secrets.cognitoClientSecret,
        issuer: secrets.cognitoDomain,
      }),
    ],
    secret: secrets.JWTSecret,
  };
};

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = buildAuthOptions();

const handler: NextAuthOptions = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The error I'm getting from the console is that

```js
- error TypeError: options.providers is not iterable
```

What is the best practice for being able to return the authOptions from an async function?

Answer (score 0):

It is explained [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization): You should get the secrets inside the handler.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

export default async function auth(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
// Fetch your configs
const options = await buildAuthOptions()
  // Do whatever you want here, before the request is passed down to `NextAuth`
  return await NextAuth(req, res, options)
}
```